# Fixing the value of Vo in this circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

I know that MOSFET is in active mode. But how can I make v0 = 2.5 V?

[image]

Comment: In the right hand circuit just swap the MOSFET with another 100 kohm resistor. Hey presto, you get 2.5 volts. The real question is how can you make the MOSFET look like 100 kohm.

Comment: @Andyaka  I understood from you!!!! I love you Mr. Andy.

Comment: Don't be so soppy LOL.

Comment: start thinking Vgs(th) @ Ids = R threshold and compare FETs for Requiv. At threshold.  We all love Andy’s dedication to this site but sometimes pedantic on rules and. XY questions. But beware Vt or Vgs(th) has a wide tolerance

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  I love you too!! Thank you to give advice for me!